# windows batch script to duplicate files in an image sequence

Tags: image, batch-file, sequence, rename

I'm looking for a little help creating a batch rename script in windows

I have a folder of images, numbered sequentially by 3, ie.

- test_01.001.tif
- test_01.004.tif
- test_01.007.tif

and so on

What i'm aiming to do is **copy and rename** each one twice so that it makes up the missing images after it, to make up the full image sequence, so that

`test_01.001.tif` is copied twice and those copies renamed to:

`test_01.002.tif` and `test_01.003.tif`

And so on for the rest of the image sequence (goes up to 200)

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%a in ('dir /B /A-D *.*.tif') do (
   set /A new1=1%%b+1, new2=new1+1
   copy "%%a.%%b.%%c" "%%a.!new1:~1!.%%c"
   copy "%%a.%%b.%%c" "%%a.!new2:~1!.%%c"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

not tested

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\the_folder_with_the_images"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%l in (1 ; 3 ; 201) do (
   set current_number=%%l
   set next_number=%%l+1
   set next_next_number=%%l+2
   if %%l lss 100 (
     set current_number=0%%l
   )
   if %%l lss 10 (
     set current_number=0%%l
   ) 

   if !next_number! lss 100 (
     set next_number=0%%l
   )
   if !next_number! lss 10 (
     set next_number=0%%l
   )

   if !next_next_number! lss 100 (
     set next_next_number=0%%l
   )
   if !next_next_number! lss 10 (
     set next_next_number=0%%l
   ) 
   copy test_01.!current_number!.tif test_01.!next_number!.tif
   copy test_01.!current_number!.tif test_01.!next_next_number!.tif
)

endlocal
```

Comment: Nice method... `pushd` and `for /l` is probably the best route to take. :D

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "basename=test_01."
FOR /l %%a IN (1001,3,1997) DO (
 SET /a filename=%%a
 IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\%basename%!filename:~-3!.tif" (
  SET /a new1=1+%%a
  SET /a new2=2+%%a
  ECHO(COPY /b "%sourcedir%\%basename%!filename:~-3!.tif" "%sourcedir%\%basename%!new1:~-3!.tif"
  ECHO(COPY /b "%sourcedir%\%basename%!filename:~-3!.tif" "%sourcedir%\%basename%!new2:~-3!.tif"
 ) else GOTO :EOF 
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required COPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files. Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file copied`)

The process varies `%%a` from 1001 to 1997 in steps of 3. If the file with a key namesection of *the last 3 digits of %%a* is not found then terminate, otherwise add 1 and 2 to `%%` giving the two required new files and copy using the same substringing technique.

Answer (score 0):

Another, very tailored, method maybe:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion    
set iter=1
set count=1

for %%i in (C:\TEST\*.tif) do (
set name=%%~dpni
pause     
    if %count%==%iter% (
        if !count! lss 10 (
        set /a count+=1
        copy "%%i" "!name:~0,-1!!count!%%~xi"
        set /a count+=1
        copy "%%i" "!name:~0,-1!!count!%%~xi"
        set /a count+=1
        )
        if !count! geq 10 if !count! lss 100 (
        set /a count+=1
        copy "%%i" "!name:~0,-2!!count!%%~xi"
        set /a count+=1
        copy "%%i" "!name:~0,-2!!count!%%~xi"
        set /a count+=1
        )
        if !count! geq 100 if !count! lss 1000 (
        set /a count+=1
        copy "%%i" "!name:~0,-3!!count!%%~xi"
        set /a count+=1
        copy "%%i" "!name:~0,-3!!count!%%~xi"
        set /a count+=1
        )

    ) else (
    set /a iter+=1
    )
)
pause
```

Change `TEST`path to the one relevant to your `*.tif` files.